# Component update but state does not update redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers, toolkit

I have a to do list app and I store the to do list in a state called list which is an array. When I add a list the component rerender and update the UI but when I console log the list after call the reducer, the list does not update. This is the console. The object before the list is for alert message

[image]

And this is my repo link : https://github.com/yustinayasin/tugas-react/tree/day16/day16

Here's my code to add the list in my component:

```
function App() {
  const [kegiatan, setKegiatan] = useState('');
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editID, setEditID] = useState(null);
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.list);
  const alert = useSelector((state) => state.alert);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!kegiatan) {
      dispatch(setAlert({show: true, msg: 'Masukkan kegiatan terlebih dahulu', type: 'danger'}))
    } else if (kegiatan && isEditing) {
      dispatch(editToList({title: kegiatan, id: editID}));
      setKegiatan('');
      setEditID(null);
      setIsEditing(false);
      dispatch(setAlert({show: true, msg: 'Kegiatan berhasil diubah', type: 'success'}));
    } else {
      console.log('masuk');
      dispatch(addToList({title: kegiatan}));
      dispatch(setAlert({show: true, msg: 'Kegiatan ditambahkan ke dalam list', type: 'success'}));
      console.log(list);
      setKegiatan('');
    }
  }

  const clearList = () => {
    dispatch(setAlert({show: true, msg: 'List kegiatan kosong', type: 'danger'}));
    dispatch(clearAllList());

  }

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    dispatch(setAlert({show: true, msg: 'Kegiatan berhasil dihapus', type: 'danger'}));
    dispatch(deleteListItem(), {id: id});
  }

  const editItem = (id) => {
    const specificItem = list.find((item) => item.id === id);
    setIsEditing(true);
    setEditID(id);
    setKegiatan(specificItem.title);
  }

  const completeItem = (id) => {
    dispatch(completeItemList({id: id}));
  }

  return (
    <section className="section-center">
      <Navbar/>
      <form className="kegiatan-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {alert.show && <Alert />}
        <h3>Daftar Kegiatan</h3>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            className="kegiatan" 
            placeholder='contoh: beli beras' 
            value={kegiatan} 
            onChange={(e) => setKegiatan(e.target.value)}
            />
          <button className="submit-btn" type="submit">
            {isEditing ? 'edit' : 'submit'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {list.length > 0 && 
        <div className="kegiatan-container">
          <List completeItem={completeItem} removeItem={removeItem} editItem={editItem}/>
          <button className="clear-btn" onClick={clearList}>
            hapus semua kegiatan
          </button>
        </div>
      }
    </section>
  );
}

export default App
```

And this is my reducer code

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  list: []
}

export const listSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'list',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToList: (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload.title);
        return [...state.list, {id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: action.payload.title, complete: false}];
    },
    editToList: (state, action) => {
        return [...state.list, state.list.map((item) => {
            if(item.id === action.payload['id']) {
                return {...item, title: action.payload['kegiatan']};
            }
            return item;
        })]
    },
    deleteListItem: (state, action) => {
        return state.list.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    clearAllList: () => {
        return initialState;
    },
    completeItemList: (state, action) => {
        return [...state.list, state['list'].map((item) => {
            if(item.id === action.payload['id']) {
                return {...item, complete: !state.list.complete};
            }
            return item;
        })]
    }
  },
})


export const { completeItemList, editToList, addToList, deleteListItem, clearAllList} = listSlice.actions

export default listSlice.reducer
```

Comment: It seems like you are logging `list` immediately after dispatching the add list action. This is why you are seeing the previous list state (i.e it appears to be logging an older version of list). An alternative to do it would be to use a `useEffect` with the list as a dependency and logging it whenever it changes. However, I would suggest using the Redux Devtools extension for your browser as a more integrated debugging solution.

Comment: @Moistbobo It works. The list update everytime. But when I want to use state in the completeList action in reducer I got an undefined value. Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try spreading the whole state before spreading just the list item within the state. Instead of :

```
return [...state.list, {id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: action.payload.title, complete: false}];,
```

do :

```
return{...state, [...state.list, {id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: action.payload.title, complete: false}];}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).